# SL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Tags: php, curl

i am using Repo script by command:

```
 curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo
```

but after that i get an error:

```
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

i read some solutions to fix this problem and i got that adding the following line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

but i want to know that  which is the file can i add this line? Please help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would add VERIFYPEER in a PHP file when making the cURL call e.g.

```
<?php 
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init(); 

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com"); 

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// set verifypeer to false
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);      
?>
```

As you are running curl from command line verifypeer will not work, you would need to use --insecure

```
curl --insecure https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo
```

---

A better solution would be to try and make sure you have SSL certificate bundles installed. E.g. on CentOS:

```
yum install ca-certificates
```

If that doesn't work you can download and include the bundle manually from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem or https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, 'ca-bundle.crt');
```

or via command line

```
curl --cacert /path/to/ca-bundle.crt https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the curl shell command with the --insecure option:

```
curl --insecure https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo
```

From the curl man page:

```
-k/--insecure
              (SSL)  This  option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure"
              SSL connections and transfers. [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your network connenction to git server was blocked!!!